# Get Document id of the template

Tags: docusignapi, document

I have the Docusign template with 3 document in that template. I have three button and on each button click i need to access the different of the template. How it can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

We consider an envelope a single unit. So we don't provide ways to just see 1 document in the envelope. You can create 3 different envelopes for your scenario if you want buttons in your app that goes to each of them separately.